# How to calculate the average of an Array[][]

Tags: java

I calculated the sum of both lengths for both arrays in order to get the average. What I'm trying to do now is to calculate the sum of numbers inside the arrays so I can calculate the standard deviation.

```
jbtnGenerate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {
            // variable for the sum
            double sum = 0; 
            // variable for standard deviation
            double ecartTypeXbarre = 0; 
            // variable to calculate the numbers but squared
            double sommeXcarre = 0; 
            double ecartType1 = 0;
            double moyenneXbarre = 0;// that's the average
            int lengths = 0;
            // Variable for Size of Samples
            int tailleEchantillon = Integer.parseInt(jtfn.getText());
            // Variable to get number of samples
            int nombreEchantillon = Integer.parseInt(jtfNbEchantillons.getText());

            // Variable where i stock both previous ones
            double echantillon[][] = new double[tailleEchantillon][nombreEchantillon]; 

            // Generates random numbers taken from data which is an ArrayList of 
            // doubles and puts it into echantillon
            for (int i = 0; i < tailleEchantillon; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nombreEchantillon; j++)
                    echantillon[i][j] = data.get(rng.nextInt(data.size()));
            }

            // puts the numbers into a TextArea
            for (int i = 0; i < tailleEchantillon; i++) { 
                for (int j = 0; j < nombreEchantillon; j++)
                    jta.append(String.valueOf(echantillon[i][j]) + "\n");
            }
              //Calculating avg and sum
           for (int i = 0; i < echantillon.length; i++) {
                    //Calculates the lengths of the first array
                    lengths += echantillon[i].length;
 //sommeXbarre is supposed to be the sum of values inside echantillon
                    sommeXbarre+= lengths;

                    double xCarre1 = lengths * lengths;

                    sommeXcarre += xCarre1;

                    //Calculates the average += echantillon
                    for (int k = 0; k < echantillon[i].length; k++) {

                        moyenneXbarre += echantillon[i][k];
                    }
                }
                                    //That's where my average is calculated
                moyenneXbarre /= lengths;
          //Trying to calculated the standard deviation 
 // Inside this ((sommeXbarre * sommeXbarre) I need the sum of numbers which Im not able to get

            ecartType1 = Math.sqrt(
                (sommeXcarre - ((sommeXbarre * sommeXbarre) / echantillon.length))
                / echantillon.length
            );

            ecartTypeXbarre = ecartType1 / Math.sqrt(tailleEchantillon);

            jtfMoyenneXBarre.setText(String.valueOf(moyenneXbarre));
            jtfEcartTypeXBarre.setText(String.valueOf(ecartTypeXbarre));
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Consider adding the information as a code comments. This is just too messy to figure out.

Comment: Alright I'll edit it now. Sorry

Comment: "I'm not sure if its actually taking the values that were randomly generated beforehand", can't you use a debugger and figure out?

Comment: I've tried using it, but it's not helping me much. I looked around on how to calculate when the array is only [] but not sure what to do when its [][]

Comment: Please have a closer look at the for loop after the comment "//Calculating the sum of the generated values just above this".

Comment: So you want to calculate one average of both dimensions of the two dimensional array or do you want to calculate an average for each of the one dimensional arrays?

Comment: I think it's not actually taking the generated values because I'm not telling it to go get it from there, but I'm not sure I'm so stuck in that zone that I might be missing on something and making a stupid mistake.

Comment: I want to calculate the sum of all the numbers that were generated and put into echantillon so then I can just do avg = sum/echantillon.length @Einar

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Code Review

Comment: Then you are way off. The enchantillon.length will only give the length of the first dimension of the array. I would suggest that you read some basic tutorial on java arrays and then post a new more precise question.

Comment: I updated my code. What I'm asking is: How would I calculate the sum of the values that are randomly generated and put in echantillon in order to get the average. I also put comments in the code to help understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sub-arrays are all the same size as if you had declared an `int[][] ray = new int[2][2];` you can more or less do this:

```
int[][] ray = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };

// ray.length == 2
// ray[0].length == 2
// ray[1].length == 2

double avg = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < ray.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < ray[i].length; k++) {
        avg += ray[i][k];
    }
}

avg /= ray.length * ray[0].length;
```

The problem is in Java they don't have to be. You can do this:

```
int[][] ray = { { 1 }, { 2, 3, 4 } };

// ray.length == 2
// ray[0].length == 1
// ray[1].length == 3
```

So really you should sum the lengths too:

```
double avg = 0;
int lengths = 0;

// loop for ray.length
// ray.length == number of arrays in ray
for (int i = 0; i < ray.length; i++) {
    lengths += ray[i].length;

    // loop for ray[i].length
    // ray[i].length == number of elements in ray[i]
    for (int k = 0; k < ray[i].length; k++) {
        avg += ray[i][k];
    }
}

avg /= lengths;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you with this. What I'm doing is I'm calculating the sum of what I think the numbers that were previously generated and then under that  `//Calculating the sum of the generated values just above this
            for (int i = 0; i < echantillon.length; i++) { 
                sum += echantillon[0][i];
                double xCarre1 = echantillon[0][i] *                 echantillon[0][i];
                sommeXcarre += xCarre1;
            }` i have this which is where I calculate the average `double moyenneXbarre = sum / echantillon.length;`

Comment: I see the attempted averaging but I'm not so sure your loop is doing what you are wanting it do. Right now it is looping through the array at echantillon[0] using indexes based on the number of arrays contained in echantillon (echantillon.length). If the arrays in your 2D array are each of length equal to the number of arrays, you won't get an error but the logic is still shaky. That is what my second example illustrates. Java multidimensional arrays can contain arrays of different lengths.

Comment: Basically what I want it to do is take the numbers I generated and then take the sum of them so I can get the average, but if I'm understanding what you mean. You're saying i need the length of both values I entered before to get the generated numbers?

Comment: The problem is that you need to divide by the number of numbers in the sum to get the average. In Java multidimensional arrays can contain arrays of different lengths so you need to be sure that you are dividing by the right number. See the comments I added to the example.

Comment: `double avg = 0;
     int lengths = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < echantillon.length; i++) {
         lengths += echantillon[i].length;

         for (int k = 0; k < echantillon[i].length; k++) {
             avg += echantillon[i][k];
         }
     }

     avg /= lengths;` so you're saying I have to do this in order to find the average? but what would the sum be in all this?

Comment: Yes, that will sum all elements in all arrays in `echantillon[][]`. And lengths will hold the total number of elements in the sum. For the array in my second example the sum will be `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` and lengths will be `1 + 3`. So avg be `(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) / (1 + 3) = 2.5`.

Comment: so lengths is the sum? lets say I were to put lengths/echantillon.lenth; it would give me the average? I have to find the sum in order to calculate other things

Comment: No, lengths is the sum of the _number of elements_ in the arrays. In my second example, `ray` has two arrays, ray[0] has one element and ray[1] has three. Finding the average of all four elements requires an extra step: you need to find the sum _but also_ you need to find the number of elements in the sum. To do that you have to sum the array lengths.

Comment: Alright I got that. That's for finding the average right? Sorry I;m a bit slow its 3am, but I am looking for the sum of the numbers in the arrays. How would I find that. see in this code `ecartType1 = Math.sqrt((sommeXcarre - ((sum* sum) / echantillon.length))/ echantillon.length);` where I wrote sum I need to put the sum of what's in the arrays so lets say there 1 2 3 4 i wanna know the sumb of those Edit: I'm going to update my original question so you see what I have so far